# Setting extent in which one raster would show and other won't

Tags: raster, extents, scale

I have 20+ raster spread out on huge area so I set the scale range (out beyond, in beyond) at which raster will be shown. But when I zoom into raster A, raster B with same scale range is also rendering even though I can't see it.

I want to know if there's a way to set **extent** at which raster will be shown so when I zoom in raster A, raster B with the same scale range doesn't render?

Comment: Which software? How do you know the raster B is rendering if you do not see it?

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4. 

I know it's rendering because I can see icon of raster B getting brighter in Table of Contents

Comment: Do you know if anything else is happening? Does ArcGIS really use CPU for rendering something outside the view port? If you zoom to area that is outside both A and B, is your processor burning?

Comment: No, if I zoom out, everything's working fine.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean zoom out but pan. Keep the scale at the level where rendering should happen but move to some area without data. Please verify that rendering those invisible rasters is really consuming resources of your computer.

Comment: Can you explain how to verify it? I tried it rendering in .mxd with all rasters and in .mxd with only one raster and the difference is obvious (I didn't measure it with stopwatch, but it's obvious). I don't know any other way to verify it.

Comment: If it is obviously slower then it is sad. Try to report that as an issue through your ESRI support.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will :) now back to question, is there a way to set that the rendering raster is only the one in current extent?

Comment: Does this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62719/arcgis-only-draw-data-in-current-layout-view work also for raster layers.

Comment: I'll try it on monday when I get to the office. It seems promising except the layout view because I need this to happen in data view. But thanks for the idea, I'll get back to you on monday.

Comment: This one is useful if you need it only in layout view or you have your features in separate data frames so for me, unfortunately, is not. But great idea for some other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to limit the extent in which should ArcGIS render raster layers in data view. It will render all layers that are possible to render.

However, as User30184 has mentioned, you can clip the extent in layout view - [explained here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62719/arcgis-only-draw-data-in-current-layout-view?noredirect=1&lq=1).